# Disabling Event Listeners In Spock Unit Test

Tags: grails, spock

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to disable event listeners in a Spock Unit Test.

I'm working on a service in a Grails app that utilizes event listeners upon saving a new object (an organization). Using a publisher and subscriber here allows me to create a new RecipientGroup and make it the organization's default group in a specific order that seems to work better with Hibernate.

Here's the save method and subscriber to the event from the save method:

```
class MyService {

    @Transactional
    @Publisher(Event.ORGANIZATION_CREATED)
    Organization save(Organization organization) {
    
        if (Organization.findByName(organization.name))
            throw new Exception('organization.create.exists')
    
        organization.save(failOnError: true)
        sendSignupNotification(organization)
        metricsService.createDefaults(organization)
    
        return organization
    }

    @Transactional
    @Subscriber(Event.ORGANIZATION_CREATED)
    void createDefaultRecipientGroup(Organization org) {
        Organization organization = organizationDataService.get(org.id)
        organization.defaultGroup = new RecipientGroup(organization: organization).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
        organization.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

However, this breaks some of my unit tests, `cannot invoke method get() on a null object` in reference to organizationDataService.get() in my subscriber method. I would prefer to split up the creation of the object and these extra tasks into different unit tests. So, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to disable the publisher or listener during my test. Also open to other ideas on how to structure this.

Here's the test:

```
void "test that the organization save method correctly sets up default Recipient group"() {
    setup:
    String foo = "foo"

    when:
    Organization organization = new Organization(name: foo)
    service.save(organization)

    and: "the default recipient group is created"
    RecipientGroup.findByOrganization(organization)

    and:
    1 * mockTextService.send(_, true)

    and:
    0 * _
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your code, read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Because the OP forgot to notify others in a comment that his question was updated, now providing substantial pieces of example code, I want to mention it, just in case @LeonardBrünings happens to be Grails-savvy. I am not. Other community members now probably can help the OP more effectively, too. My guess is that the Grails testing guide explains somewhere how to mock event subscribers.

Comment: "My guess is that the Grails testing guide explains somewhere how to mock event subscribers. " - As far as I know we don't publish anything about how to mock event subscribers in particular, but the mechanism for replacing those beans are the same as any other beans.  There isn't enough information in the question to know for sure, but I suspect overriding `doWithSpring` to provide a custom `organizationDataService` bean will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting this because I have a viable workaround to this now. Unit tests appear to only pick up publisher/subscriber annotations in the class being tested. Moving the subscriber into a different service is allowing the desired behavior of disabling the event listener for testing, so I can then build out separate unit tests for the two methods in question:

```
class MyService1 {

    @Transactional
    @Publisher(Event.ORGANIZATION_CREATED)
    Organization save(Organization organization) {
    
        if (Organization.findByName(organization.name)) throw new Exception('organization.create.exists')
    
        organization.save(failOnError: true)
        sendSignupNotification(organization)
        metricsService.createDefaults(organization)
    
        return organization
    }
}
```

```
class MyService2 {

    @Transactional
    @Subscriber(Event.ORGANIZATION_CREATED)
    void createDefaultRecipientGroup(Organization org) {
        Organization organization = organizationDataService.get(org.id)
        organization.defaultGroup = new RecipientGroup(organization: organization).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        organization.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```